# Cual seria la mejor manera de guardar una lista ligada en un archivo binario? c++

Tags: c++

Comencé a aprender c++ hace poco e intentando guardar esta lista:

```
struct Client_node {
    string name;
    string alias;
    string telefono;
    string email;
    int numero_de_ventas;
    Client_node* siguiente;
};
Client_node* principio;
Client_node* actual;
```

Usando este método:

```
ofstream escritura_clientes;
    escritura_clientes.open("clientes.bin",ios::out,ios::binary);
    if (escritura_clientes.is_open())
    {
        actual = principio;
        while (actual != nullptr) {
            /*escritura_clientes.write(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&actual), sizeof(Client_node));*/
            actual = actual->siguiente;
        }

    }
    escritura_clientes.close();
```

me he topado con algunos errores, en ocasiones no se guarda la información completa, así que me gustaría preguntar, cual seria el mejor método de guardar esta información en un archivo binario?

Comment: Vas por buen camino. El problema es que los punteros de la lista no serán los mismos cuando la regeneres. Tendrás que preservar las conexiones entre nodos de otra manera. Por ejemplo, se me ocurre que podrías guardar solo la información de cada nodo (en el archivo) como si se tratara de un arreglo. A la hora de recrear la lista tendrás que reasignar `siguiente` a la dirección correcta.